# How to resize canvas and background layer in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers, resize, canvas

I want to reduce the canvas size (and the background layer) from 500×500px to 16×16px. How to resize the canvas in GIMP?

Comment: What have you tried? When learning a new software, take your time to explore the menu items

Comment: And read the [user manual](https://docs.gimp.org/en/).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to resize the contents as well (layers, paths...) see `Image>Scale image`. If you want to just reduce the canvas size, see `Image>Canvas size`. If you have a 16x16 layer in the middle of  large canvas, `Image>Fit canvas to layers` can also be a solution.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the gif. Beginners like me have a hard time finding whats where.

Comment: if you want to cut out a piece of an image its a bit more tricky. you have to cut it out then `ctrl + a` `delete` then delete the layer from the right side panel then paste and then fit canvas to image works.

Comment: @raven Much simpler actually... Just [use the Crop tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-crop.html), or make a selection, and `Image > Crop to selection`